# Retrieve user id from RTDN and in_app_purchase

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

I'm using [in_app_purchase](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase) plugin on my flutter project. I've set up the real time notification from Google Play Console to get information about subscriptions status change.
For manage Apple purchases, I send in applicationUsername (user id)
`PurchaseParam( productDetails: productDetails, applicationUserName: SessionData().currentUser?.id);`
to purchase params and then I receive them in my backend with Apple notification as appAccountToken.
I need to do the same thing with android purchases so I can associate each purchase to a user but I don't receive this information in backend.
Is there something that I can do? Thank you!

Something that makes possible the association between purchase and user id.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.